# Excel VBA-Mkdir returns path not found

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that will allow the user to select some photos and copy them to a specific folder. The folder should be created using the date and a value from a combo box.

When I am trying to run the code I get a run time error " Path not found" on the MKdir Function, I checked and all the paths previous to that point are correct.

Any ideas for what is leading to this error?

Thanks

```
'Add photos
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim fileExplorer As Integer
Dim photo As String
Dim Path1 As String
Dim P As String
Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject

Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = True
fileExplorer = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

If fileExplorer <> 0 Then

   photo = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)

Else

MsgBox ("None file has been selected")

Exit Sub

End If

dt_value = DTPicker1.Value
Syst = ComboBox1.Value

Path1 = dt_value & "-" & Syst

P = "C:\Folder" & "\" & Path1

MkDir (P)

Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Call FSO.CopyFile(photo, P, False)

MsgBox ("Your photos have been imported")

End Sub
```

Comment: You're building `Path1` from a `Date`. Does it contain path separators (`\\`)?

Comment: Either dt_value or Syst contain not valid values for a path like /

Comment: There's also no reason to use `MkDir` when you have a `FileSystemObject` - I'd suggest using [`FileSystemObject.CreateFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/createfolder-method) instead.

Comment: @Comintern Do you mean the dates? This the dt_value variable from the local window #05/02/2019#

Comment: As noted above, you need to format the date to remove the slashes.